# Displaying MySQL results in PHP by Column Value

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

I have a MySQL query that joins a few tables together to gather data for display. My goal is to display the data by a column called 'project_id'. example:

```
[project_id][project_name][order_date][ordered_by]
[31][project_a][2013-04-15][1]
[31][project_a][2013-04-16][1]
[31][project_a][2013-04-21][1]
[41][project_c][2013-02-21][1]
[41][project_c][2013-02-27][1]
```

So my problem is that I am unsure how to loop through the array of data to display the project_id once, then the data that goes with it below, because I will be using jQuery to toggle/show the group data by project_id

Here's my mysql query:

```
SELECT p.user_customer_id,
       p.name AS 'project_name',
       p.project_id,
       o.order_id,
       o.order_date,
       o.order_tech,
       pro.name,
       pro.purchase_price,
       pro.sell_price
FROM project AS p
JOIN `order` AS o ON p.project_id = o.project_id
JOIN products_in_orders AS pir ON o.order_id = pir.order_id
JOIN product AS pro ON pir.product_id = pro.product_id
WHERE p.user_customer_id = 51
ORDER BY p.project_id ASC
```

Comment: I don't understand. The example output you gave doesn't do what you wrote in the question.

Comment: the output was just an example. the actual output would be the values in the SELECT statement of the query

Comment: But in your example, you repeat the same ID, while your question says you want to display the project ID only once. I expect the example to demonstrate what you hope to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

```
<?php

/** @var $mysqli mysqli */
$result = $mysqli->query($yourOrderedQuery);

while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    // first row with this project_name
    if ($project_name != $row->project_name)
    {
        $project_name = $row->project_name; // remember we have seen this project (now)
        // display $row->project_id, etc.
    }
    // second or later row of with this project_name
    else
    {
        // display data of project from $row->order_date, etc.
    }
}
```